# JCombobox not working on jar

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, embedded-resource

I have one application that fills a JComboBox with the content of a text file (.db precisely). Everything works fine on IDE, however when creating a .jar nothing show on the JComboBox.

The code is as following:

```
private void fill(String type) throws FileNotFoundException {
    BufferedReader input = null; // used to read file content
    try {
        input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("pack"+ File.separator +type+".db")); // loading the file based on previous box (see image).
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Calc.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null,  ex);
    }
    try {
        String line = null;
        while (( line = input.readLine()) != null){
            type_list.addItem(line); // adding to my JComboBox
    }
    input.close();`
```

As stated everything works fine on netbeans IDE and I get the following

[IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7Tvr.png)

However on .jar I get the following:

[JAR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjtxn.png)

I  tried reading the file from inputStream, with no success. I'm compiling the .db files with my application, but it's not mandatory for me (I can have .jar+ db files separately).

Thank you!!!

--------------------EDIT-------------------------------

I solved the problem using

```
    InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("file.db");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
```

Thank you so much for the help :)

Comment: If the file is ever going to be in a jar, `File` will not work. You will need to use `classloader.getResourceAsStream("/path/to.db")` instead

Comment: You mean constructing a InputStream with classloader and then using a buffered reader to read lines? I tried this with no success.

Answer (score 1):

By the time of deployment, those resources will likely become an [embedded-resource](/questions/tagged/embedded-resource).  That being the case, the resource must be accessed by `URL` instead of `File`.  See the [info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for the tag, for a way to form an `URL`.